# Why is programatically joining to windows domain failing?

Tags: windows, domain, authentication, windows-domain

WE are facing an issue for a particular customer where programatically joining a machine to a domain is failing. The machine is cloned from a parent VM and attempted to be joined to the domain using windows NetJoinDomain API.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmjoin/nf-lmjoin-netjoindomain

We are doing an unsecure join using machine password. Connectivity to the Domain controller is fine and it works if we try to join to the domain manually. Also, program tic domain join is working  for other customers. So I suspect there is some setting in their DC which is rejecting unsecure joins using machine password. How to confirm this and/or debug further. Any pointers on this would be highly appreciated.

The error message is I am getting is -- (0x5): Access is denied.

PS: Also a strange this is that this does-not happen if parent VM is NOT joined to the domain

Comment: Please add more information about what you are doing and the error you are getting.

Comment: The error message is (0x5): Access is denied.

Comment: This is still unclear, including how the PS relates to your problem.

Comment: What I am saying is that if the parent VM is not joined to the domain and cloned, the NetJoinDomain API on the clone is successful , but if the parent VM is joined to the domain and then cloned, NetJoinDomain API on the clone fails with the comment I have mentioned (Access is denied). This seems strange to me, so added this if it might give some clue to others.

Comment: It seems logical to me that joining an already joined computer/VM gives such an error, perhaps caused by the currently joined domain being refused by the new one.

Comment: The newly cloned VM has a new name and SID, distinct from its parent. The same is working in our lab successfully and for other customers. Also, manual domain join of the cloned VM is successful

Comment: The NetJoinDomain function defines the code ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED as: "Access is denied. This error is returned if the caller was not a member of the Administrators local group on the target computer". Is the program being run under the wrong user account or with insufficient permissions (perhaps elevation is required)?

Comment: The code invoking the NetJoinDomain API is configured to run as a windows service. And this windows service has LogOn type configured as Local System account. so what can be done here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the
[NetJoinDomain function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmjoin/nf-lmjoin-netjoindomain)
from a system service running under the
[LocalSystem account](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localservice-account),
described as:

> The LocalService account is a predefined local account used by the service control manager. It has minimum privileges on the local computer and **presents anonymous credentials on the network**.

As a result, you are getting the code ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, defined as:
"Access is denied. This error is returned if the caller was not a member of the Administrators local group on the target computer".

Perhaps you meant running the service under the
[NetworkService Account](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/networkservice-account?redirectedfrom=MSDN),
described as:

> A service that runs in the context of the NetworkService account **presents the computer's credentials to remote servers**.
> By default, the remote token contains SIDs for the Everyone and Authenticated Users groups.

Although this account also does not present administrator credentials, so will not
be able to join the domain.

You should better create this service as running under a local administrator account.

Although this should work, I personally don't like the idea of a system service
doing the domain join. Such actions should be done openly and under user
supervision.